# Byte-array to float using bitwise shifting instead of BitConverter

Tags: c#, mono, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm receiving byte-arrays containing float variables (32 bit).
In my C# application I'd like to turn `byte[] byteArray` into a float using bitwise shifting (because it's a lot faster than BitConverter).

Turning a byte-array into a `short` works like this:

`short shortVal = (short)((short)inputBuffer [i++] << 8 | inputBuffer [i++]);`

**How do I do this for float-variables?**

Comment: You can do the same thing with float, at-least for me if I understood your question right

Comment: BitConverter [uses bitshifting internally](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,e8230d40857425ba). You could copy that code and remove the contract checks, big-endian branch, etc.

Comment: How can you know an approach is faster if you haven't implemented it yet? How did you measure to know it was faster?

Comment: someone on codereview who gave me the tip was kind enough to provide a quick comparison, see here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95983/read-binary-serial-data-and-parse-integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's gut the BCL and use its intestines for our purposes:

```
    unsafe public static float ToSingle (byte[] value, int startIndex)
    {
        int val = ToInt32(value, startIndex);
        return *(float*)&val;
    }
```

You can implement `ToInt32` using bit shifting.

If you don't need endianness behavior a single unsafe access can give you the float (assuming it's aligned).

Alternatively, you can use a union struct to convert an int to a float.

Comment: can you explain this construct: `*(float*)&val;` ? It looks like a `union`

Comment: That unsafe memory access. This simply looks at the int bytes as a float. It's a reinterpretation of those bytes. You can do that using the union struct idea if you like that better. Search "c# union".

Answer (score 0):

To get away from C# conventional methods and obtain fast performance, you'll most likely have to implement "unsafe" behavior. You could do something like the C style memory copy.

```
unsafe public static void MemoryCopy (void* memFrom, void* memTo, int size) {
    byte* pFrom = (byte*)memFrom;
    byte* pTo = (byte*)memTo;
    while (size-- >= 0)
        *pTo++ = *pFrom++;
}
```

This assumes that the float's endianness is the same going into the byte[] as it on the other end.

To use this you'll have to first fix the byte array since the runtime can move it anytime it wants during garbage collection. Something like this:

```
float f;

unsafe {
    fixed (byte* ptr = byteArray) {
        MemoryCopy (ptr, &f, sizeof(float));
    }
}
```